# drupal 7 Upload or download content of Views as file

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a View displaying the content type in table format.

I wanted to download or save that table as excel file or to any other file so i can store that content. Is there any modules to do that. I am working on drupal 7 .

Please reply me if there is any solution because i have been trying to do this all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [views data export module](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) to export views as csv, xls, etc.

You may also check the similar modules section on the modules page for other modules that offer exporting.